# Scheduled a computer to reboot everyday at 7AM, not sure if I did it correctly

Tags: command-line, shutdown, cron

Running Ubuntu 20.04, I have computers that I want to reboot everyday at 7AM. I followed these instructions, and I thought it was working, but now when I use the `uptime` command, it will often report longer than 24 hours, which if it reboots daily, it should never exceed.

These were the instructions I used.

To schedule a daily reboot at 7 AM on a Linux system, you can use the cron scheduler. Open your crontab file by running:

`crontab -e`

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.

```
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
  3. /bin/ed
```

choose `option 1` for the editor

Then, add the following line to reboot everyday at 7 AM:

`0 7 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now`

Save the file, and the system will reboot everyday at 7 AM.

In this example:

```
•   Minute: 0
•   Hour: 7 (7 AM)
•   Day of the month: * (every day of the month)
•   Month: * (every month)
•   Day of the week: * (every day of the week)
```

This line specifies that the system will reboot every day at 7 AM. Save the file after making this modification.

I did the CTRL X and saved the file (`File Name to Write: /tmp/crontab.GO6Qpc/crontab`), was back at the terminal prompt and rebooted. Is there anything else I need to do? Did I save it in the correct place? Do I need to add any `sudo` commands anywhere?

Comment: You can use `crontab -l` to verify ... Also a reboot might need elevated privileges if other users are logged in at the time the cronjob is executed and that can be done by adding that line to `root`'s crontab with `sudo crontab -e` instead of the current user's crontab i.e. `crontab -e` like you did.

Comment: Thank you @Raffa, the `sudo crontab -e` was what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your, cronjob and logic is correct syntax-wise and you can verify if you succeeded in installing the new crontab for your user with:

```
crontab -l
```

... and you should see your added cronjob listed in the output.

**That said**, a **reboot** might need to be issued by a user with elevated privileges in some cases like if other users are logged in or an inhibitor is set by a service/application at the time the cronjob is executed and in which cases, CRON invoked as a regular user will fail to execute that command.

**Therefore**, you should probably be installing such cronjobs to `root`'s crontab instead with `sudo` like so:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

... and to list cronjobs for `root`, use `sudo` as well like so:

```
sudo crontab -l
```